# Why is my script failing me? get ip

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Why is my script not managing to get the correct information and inserting it into the database.

I want to get the client IP , and the time/ date.

My `$ip` function

```
<?php // Function to get the client IP address
function get_ip_address() {
    // check for shared internet/ISP IP
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }

    // check for IPs passing through proxies
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        // check if multiple ips exist in var
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], ',') !== false) {
            $iplist = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
            foreach ($iplist as $ip) {
                if (validate_ip($ip))
                    return $ip;
            }
        } else {
            if (validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
                return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
    }
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP'];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];

    // return unreliable ip since all else failed
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

/**
 * Ensures an ip address is both a valid IP and does not fall within
 * a private network range.
 */
function validate_ip($ip) {
    if (strtolower($ip) === 'unknown')
        return false;

    // generate ipv4 network address
    $ip = ip2long($ip);

    // if the ip is set and not equivalent to 255.255.255.255
    if ($ip !== false && $ip !== -1) {
        // make sure to get unsigned long representation of ip
        // due to discrepancies between 32 and 64 bit OSes and
        // signed numbers (ints default to signed in PHP)
        $ip = sprintf('%u', $ip);
        // do private network range checking
        if ($ip >= 0 && $ip <= 50331647) return false;
        if ($ip >= 167772160 && $ip <= 184549375) return false;
        if ($ip >= 2130706432 && $ip <= 2147483647) return false;
        if ($ip >= 2851995648 && $ip <= 2852061183) return false;
        if ($ip >= 2886729728 && $ip <= 2887778303) return false;
        if ($ip >= 3221225984 && $ip <= 3221226239) return false;
        if ($ip >= 3232235520 && $ip <= 3232301055) return false;
        if ($ip >= 4294967040) return false;
    }
    return true;
} ?>
```

Here is the query its-self

```
$query = "INSERT INTO voted (ip, time, server) VALUES ('$ip', 'now()', '$id')";
```

Here is how it inserts into the database:

[image]

http://rs-list.com

Comment: Are you doing any error checking?

Comment: The date does not go into the database because NOW() is a MySQL function. You should not use quotes there. So your query should look like this `$query = "INSERT INTO voted (ip, time, server) VALUES ('$ip', NOW(), '$id')";`
To help you with the inserting of the IP, could you please provide the code where and how you set the value to your $ip variable before using it in the query?

Comment: [`NOW()` is a function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and not a string literal. which is what you're using it as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes around [`now()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html); it is a function. MySQL is treating it as a string literal and will use default time format because the received format is invalid.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO voted (ip, time, server) VALUES ('$ip', NOW(), '$id')";
```

About the `$ip` value. I guess your `validate_ip` function is returning `false`, this will cause the value 0 to be entered in the database. When I execute your `get_ip_address` function I will get my ip address.

Comment: What about the $ip, thats also not working :\

Comment: Where are you declaring the variable `$ip`, I miss that part.

Comment: Very good question that, I just tried $ip = get_ip_address(); , But failed to work

Comment: Probably your IP is excluded by the `validate_ip` function.

Comment: Fixed that , but look at this? http://prntscr.com/7iere2   funny looking ip :O

Comment: When you remove the validate ip method, you also need to removed the checks using the validate ip method in the get_ip_address function.

Comment: What datatype is that column? Is it an integer or a varchar or something like that?

Comment: It is an int, here is the table structure :  http://prntscr.com/7iet2x, and also @Andizer, i did remove the checks from the get ip function: http://pastebin.com/xwMQb0m1

Comment: Column type is integer. That ain't gonna work. I would change that into varchar 60 or something like that.